# How do the Sorcerer Bloodline Feats work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

Me and one of my players are going over the characters. We noticed that the bloodlines provide bonus feats but it isn't stated what level they can get it. Thus I am not sure on how they acquire the feats. Do they get all those bonus feats at the beginning or do you get it when they level up and get one of the bonus feats on the level they normally get a feat?

Comment: Got a link to the relevant SRD page(s)?

Comment: http://paizo.com/prd/classes/sorcerer.html well this is the page concerning the bloodlines.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Sorcerer table (the one which also lists spells known) has a column named Special which mentions the levels at which you acquire a bloodline feat. You pick up a new feat from within your Bloodline's feats list at 7th, 13th and 19th level. Like [the description](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/sorcerer.html) says

> At 7th level, and every six levels thereafter, a sorcerer receives one bonus feat, chosen from a list specific to each bloodline. The sorcerer must meet the prerequisites for these bonus feats.

Naturally, as a bonus feat, this is picked up independently of regular progression: this doesn't use up feat slots you'd gain normally, you get it in addition to those.